# Correct way to pass a link to an email template in django

Tags: django, string, hyperlink, django-views

So I want to add a link to a specific page of my app in my email template, but this page changes based on the different values I pass on to my template through my view,so i tried to pass the name of the url into the template like the following but it doesn't work. Can someone please show me the right way to do something like this?

views.py

```
html_message = loader.render_to_string(
            'catalog/email_template.html',
            {'body_message': body_message,
             'user': user_obj_to.get_full_name(),
             'link': link
             },
        )

        send_mail(
            email_subject,
            body_message,
            sender_email,
            [receiver_email],
            fail_silently=False,
            html_message=html_message
        )
```

email_template.html

```
<p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">Dear {{ user }}</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">{{ body_message }} <a href="{% url '{{ link|safe }}' %}">link</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I usually do it. Create your url in View.py and pass it to your html template.

```
#Get the template
htmly = get_template('email_templates/welcome.html')

#create your url here
my_url = some_url_maker_function()

#create a context
d = {'name': form.cleaned_data['first_name'] + " " + form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
     'username': form.cleaned_data['username'], 'my_url': my_url}

subject, from_email, to = 'Subject line', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, form.cleaned_data['email']

#pass the context to html template
html_content = htmly.render(d)

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])

msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

msg.send()
```

in html template you can have this.

```
<p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">Dear {{ user }}</p>
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 15px;">{{ body_message }} <a href="{% url '{{ my_url }}' %}">link</a></p>
```

I have not tested this code. may be some tweaking required.